# I have closed all my brackets/parenthesis, but python isn't recognizing the closing bracket

Tags: python, pandas

I have everything else set up, my dataframes, etc. I have used this same process and simply copy and pasted it (I needed different code for different data sets, they had different requirements later on)
When I got to a step I have repeated, I am simply using `pandas.concat` like I have used many times before.

```
data = pd.concat([data_westint[['Date', 'total_lmp']], data_western['total_lmp'], data_aepgen['total_lmp'], data_atsigen['total_lmp'], data_chicagogen['total_lmp'], data_chicago['total_lmp'], data_dominion['total_lmp'], data_eastern['total_lmp'], data_nillinois['total_lmp'], data_nj['total_lmp'], data_ohio['total_lmp'], data_aepdaytondata = pd.concat([data_westint['Date', 'total_lmp']], data_western['total_lmp'], data_aepgen['total_lmp'], data_atsigen['total_lmp'], data_chicagogen['total_lmp'], data_chicago['total_lmp'], data_dominion['total_lmp'], data_eastern['total_lmp'], data_nillinois['total_lmp'], data_nj['total_lmp'], data_ohio['total_lmp'], data_aepdayton['total_lmp']], axis=1)
```

```
SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '(' is the error I get
```

It is saying the last bracket, (the one before `, axis`) isn't closed.

I have tried adding another bracket in front, or removing the first bracket, but nothing works. Any advice?

Comment: First of all, that's a massive line. You should be wrapping long lines of code. [PEP 8 recommends at 80 characters](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), but other folks prefer up to like 120 (especially considering pandas, which uses chaining so much and sometimes long names).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: You have 2 cases of `pd.concat()`, the second one is not closed properly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgDmt.png. If you're not already doing so, use an editor/IDE that has syntax highlighting and/or bracket matching, and avoid long lines of code; it makes these kinds of errors easier to spot and fix.

Comment: In the future, make a [mre], which can help catch basic mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a copy/paste problem. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
data = pd.concat(
    [data_westint[['Date', 'total_lmp']],
     data_western['total_lmp'],
     data_aepgen['total_lmp'],
     data_atsigen['total_lmp'],
     data_chicagogen['total_lmp'],
     data_chicago['total_lmp'],
     data_dominion['total_lmp'],
     data_eastern['total_lmp'],
     data_nillinois['total_lmp'],
     data_nj['total_lmp'],
     data_ohio['total_lmp'],
     data_aepdayton['total_lmp']],
    axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have split that massive line of code into multiple lines, you would have immediately spotted the problem(s):

```python
data = pd.concat(
    [
        data_westint[['Date', 'total_lmp']],
        data_western['total_lmp'],
        data_aepgen['total_lmp'],
        data_atsigen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicagogen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicago['total_lmp'],
        data_dominion['total_lmp'],
        data_eastern['total_lmp'],
        data_nillinois['total_lmp'],
        data_nj['total_lmp'],
        data_ohio['total_lmp'],
        data_aepdaytondata = pd.concat( # Uh, what?
            [
                data_westint['Date', 'total_lmp']
            ],
            data_western['total_lmp'],
            data_aepgen['total_lmp'],
            data_atsigen['total_lmp'],
            data_chicagogen['total_lmp'],
            data_chicago['total_lmp'],
            data_dominion['total_lmp'],
            data_eastern['total_lmp'],
            data_nillinois['total_lmp'],
            data_nj['total_lmp'],
            data_ohio['total_lmp'],
            data_aepdayton['total_lmp']
        ], # ???
            axis=1
        )
```

This is what you wrote. I just added newlines and indentation.

---

Seems like you wanted:

```python
data = pd.concat(
    [
        data_westint[['Date', 'total_lmp']],
        data_western['total_lmp'],
        data_aepgen['total_lmp'],
        data_atsigen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicagogen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicago['total_lmp'],
        data_dominion['total_lmp'],
        data_eastern['total_lmp'],
        data_nillinois['total_lmp'],
        data_nj['total_lmp'],
        data_ohio['total_lmp'],
        data_aepdaytondata = pd.concat([data_westint['Date', 'total_lmp']]),
        data_western['total_lmp'],
        data_aepgen['total_lmp'],
        data_atsigen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicagogen['total_lmp'],
        data_chicago['total_lmp'],
        data_dominion['total_lmp'],
        data_eastern['total_lmp'],
        data_nillinois['total_lmp'],
        data_nj['total_lmp'],
        data_ohio['total_lmp'],
        data_aepdayton['total_lmp']
    ],
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: That's invalid syntax. I think OP actually accidentally pasted some code twice. Look how most of the names are repeated and `data_aepdaytondata = pd.concat(` is `data_aepdayton` + `data = pd.concat(`. See [Flumenque's answer](/a/76632941/4518341).

Comment: That was my first thought, too. However, I was thrown off by @TimLewis' comment/screenshot, in which he basically proposes the same solution - I'm not familiar with pandas, so I thought maybe there is some pandas magic going on here that I don't understand. But yes of course, this is just a list-literal, and that syntax is not valid.

Comment: Good catch with the repeats!

Comment: Sorry about any confusion my screenshot caused! I'm not a Python dev either, so while the syntax error was obvious (missing brackets are easy to see when highlighted in VSCode), I assumed what they were trying to do was valid Python syntax. Plus in PHP (my main dev language), having assignment inline like that is totally valid `['one' => $another = 1, 'two' => $another + 1]` (redundant example, but syntactically valid). Didn't think it would be a copy/paste error, but seems like that was the case... My bad! 